# Inserting a text file into a hashtable with c#

Tags: c#, hashtable

i have a text file witch contains values like this :

```
0000000000
0000111222
0000144785
```

i need to insert this file into a HashTable with c#, this is what i've done so far :

```
        string[] FileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:TestHash.txt");

        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

        foreach (string line in FileLines)
        {
            //  dont know what to do here
        }
```

and after this i need to match a value from a textbox with the hashtable values. what should i do?

Comment: why a `Hashtable` and not a `Hashset<string>`?

Comment: A hashtable has a key and a value. What did you want to do? Insert the file line as the key and the value? Use something else for the key?

Comment: Try `hashtable.add(hashtable.count.ToString(), line);`

Comment: @DanielShillcock Inserting an array into a hashtable with the index as key will make lookup performance **worse**. I don't think that's what the OP is after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Hashtable` is a container for key-value-pairs. Since you only have values, not key-value-pairs, you don't need a hashtable, you need a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<string> fileLineSet = new HashSet<string>(FileLines);
```

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to use a hash set (including an example).

Comment: that works but how to do the matching thing? can you give an approach?

Answer (score 2):

This reads all lines into a HashSet and checks the value of a TextBox against

```
HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(@"D:\TestHash.txt"));
bool hasValue = items.Contains(TextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] FileLines = File.ReadAllLines("your text file path");

        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

        foreach (string line in FileLines)
        {
            if (!hashtable.ContainsKey(line))
            {
                hashtable[line] = line;
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in hashtable.Values)
        {
            //here you can match with your text box values...
            //why you need to insert text file data into hash table really i dont know.from above foreach loop inside only you can match the values.might be you have some requirement for hash table i hope
            string textboxVal = "text1";
            if (item == textboxVal)
            {
                //both are matched.do your logic
            }
            else{
                //not matched.
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi fubo,i hope my answer might be helpful to you.

Comment: Can you add a little explanation for your code? It will help us in understanding the answer.

Comment: Reading textfile data into FileLines variable.At first foreach loop looping the file data and save those values into hash table as hash table keys and vaues,here avoiding to add duplicates record to hash table by if condition. later looping the hash table values and matching with textbox value.